# Transform dataframe columns using column selector (Cols) fails

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am wondering why I cannot use the `Cols` column selector in `transform` to change a dataframe column. For instance:

```
df = DataFrame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
transform(df, [:x, :y] .=> v -> v .+ 100)    # OK
df[!, Cols(1:2)] .= df[!, Cols(1:2)] .+ 100  # OK

transform(df, Cols(1:2) .=> v -> v .+ 100)   # MethodError: no method matching length(::Cols{Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}}})
```

I've read in the `DataFrames` documentation that says column selectors such as `Cols`, `Between`, `Not`, and `All` can be used in `transform`, among others, but yet I get this error.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These selectors can be used when they are passed to `transform` directly. Here you are using broadcasting with `.=>` (note the dot), so you are not passing them directly to `transform`, but instead try pass the following:

```
julia> Cols(1:2) .=> v -> v .+ 100
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Cols{Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}}})
```

The error you observe is not emitted by DataFrames.jl but by Julia base.

What you need to do is to use `names` to make things work:

```
julia> names(df, Cols(1:2)) .=> v -> v .+ 100
2-element Vector{Pair{String, var"#7#8"}}:
 "x" => var"#7#8"()
 "y" => var"#7#8"()
```

and in consequence the following works:

```
 transform(df, names(df, Cols(1:2)) .=> v -> v .+ 100)
```

In the future the functionality you request might be added but it requires changes in DataAPI.jl, see [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataAPI.jl/pull/10).

---

EDIT

As signaled in the original answer in DataFrames.jl 1.3 the functionality has been added and now you can do `transform(df, Cols(1:2) .=> v -> v .+ 100)` without error. See https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2021/12/17/selectors.html for an explanation how it works now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think I'd have figure this out myself.

Comment: Looks like its working now, in `julia 1.7` I am able to do this: `transform(df, Cols(1) => (x -> 0.0) => :scalar_col)`

Comment: Yes - this works now.